# Rewrite c++ text encoder to python

Tags: python, c++, python-2.7

I have the following code in c++:

```
for(const char *x = r.ptr, *end = r.ptr + r.len; x != end; ++x) { 
    switch(*x) {
        case 0x5c:
        case 0x22:
            pc->output[0] = '\\'; pc->output[1] = *x; pc->output += 2;
            break;
        case 0xa:
            pc->output[0] = '\\'; pc->output[1] = 'n'; pc->output += 2;
            break;
        case 0xd:
            pc->output[0] = '\\'; pc->output[1] = 'r'; pc->output += 2;
            break;
        default:
            if(str_escape_2_hex(*x)) {
                impl::escape_char_hex(pc->output, *x);
            } else {
                *pc->output = *x; pc->output++;
            }
    }
}
```

And I want to rewrite it to python 2 because I need the same encoder there. I tried with this:

```
def encode_akv_fields(data):
    hexlify = codecs.getencoder('hex')
    for i, el in enumerate(str(data)):
        if hexlify(el)[0] in ('5c', '22'):  # \\ or "
            data[i].encode('hex') = '\\' + hexlify(el)[0]
        elif hexlify(el)[0] == '0a':  # \n
            data[i].encode('hex') = '\\n'
        elif hexlify(el)[0] == '0d':  # \r
            data[i].encode('hex') = '\\r'
        elif '1f' >= hexlify(el)[0] >= '7f':
            tmp3 = (hexlify(el)[0] >> 4) & '0f'.decode('hex')
            data[i].encode('hex') = '\\x'
    return data
```

but it doesn't work - I got

> SyntaxError: can't assign to function call

Data is a string or dict with values that I want to log. Those logs needs to be in AKV format (Apache key value). And for this to work I need some hex values to be encoded like it is in c++ (the code in c++ works).

How should I create the same encoder in python as I did in c++?

Comment: Was that extra indentation of the for loop unintended? If not, that may be one of the issues you're facing.

Comment: Can you clarify what kind of incorrect behavior you are getting? A runtime error? (if so, what kind) An incorrect result?

Comment: I fixed identation and added the error I got. I don't know how to write/change hex value of specific character.

Comment: `data[i].encode('hex') = '\\x'` you cannot assign to the result of a function call. But can you provide your input (what is `data`) and what do you expect as output? the question is unanswerable right now, there are errors following that one. Only way to answer properly is to fix your code, but we cannot reproduce.

Comment: A few questions. What is `pc->output`, what are `impl::escape_char_hex` and `str_escape_2_hex`?

Comment: Your C++ code does a very simple thing: assigns the current character in the array and increments the pointer. In order to encode e.g.  a `\\n` it assigns a '\\', increments, assigns a 'n', increments. What your Python code tries to do is a mystery. What's a `data`? Is it your input or output? What type `data[i]` is? Is it a string? If not, why are you trying to assign a string of length >1 to it? Why not do the same thing your C++ code does, namely, assign one character at a time and move the thing that points to the current character?

Comment: Alternatively, why not do the even easier thing, start with an empty output string and *append* the result of encoding each character to it?